# Get columns with the max value accounting for ties in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

let's say that we have this pandas DF.

I want to know which column has the maximum value per row

[image]

The output for row 1,2 and 3 would be all the 5 columns

For row 4 would be `visits_total`

And for row 5 would be `['content_gene_strength', 'sport_gene_strength', 'visits_total']`

Thanks

Comment: [Please don't post images of code/data (or links to them)](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Compare all columns by [`DataFrame.eq`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.eq.html) by maximal value, then use [`DataFrame.dot`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.dot.html) for matrix multiplication with columns names with separator, last remove separator from right side by [`Series.str.rstrip`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.rstrip.html):

```
df['new'] = df.eq(df.max(axis=1), axis=0).dot(df.columns + ',').str.rstrip(',')
```